# Como apresentar dados pelo DOM sem ser por tabela

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, dom

Olá, estou com uma duvida na aplicação que estou criando, estou trabalhando com um banco de dados Oracle, e estou trazendo as informações do banco e apresentando na tela por meio de tabela, mas queria tentar trabalhar separadamente com esses dados, por exemplo criar um paragrafo e apresentar um valor.

Só consegui fazer a apresentação dos dados por meio de tabela, existe outra forma? Agradeço demais se alguém puder me ajuda nisso.

Aceito todas as dicas para melhorar o código.

Minha página **Index.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Apontamentos da Produção</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

  <div id="data"></div>

  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="texto"> PAINEL-1 | APONTAMENTOS DA PRODUÇÃO</div>
      <div class="clock"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <!-- Tabela principal, apresentando os apontamentos -->
  <table id="table" class="tablePrincipal">
    <tr class="trPrincipal">
      <th class="th2" style="width: 11%;">Data</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 8%; ">Hora</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 5%;">Orig.</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 8%;">O.P.</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 10%;">Produto</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 8%;">Deriv.</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 9%;">Peso (TN)</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 7%;">Refugo (TN)</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 13%;">Lote</th>
      <th class="th2" style="width: 60%;;">Operador</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <br>

</body>

<script>

// Tabela de apontamentos. Listagem.

  // Aqui é onde é feito o push de informações, chamando pelo caminho e colocando o ID da tabela que ele vai levar as informações

  window.onload = function () {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/teste')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        var table = document.getElementById('table');

        // Primeiro define a variavel, e coloca o comando para inserir uma linha, é tudo organizado por rows
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
          var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
          var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
          var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
          var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
          var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
          var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
          var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
          var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
          var cell8 = row.insertCell(7);
          var cell9 = row.insertCell(8);
          var cell10 = row.insertCell(9);

          // Queria trabalhar com os dados separadamente, tentar criar um <p> e colocar um dado para apresentar.

        // Queria tentar fazer um calculo com essa variável, mas não funciona assim
          var cell11 = cell7 * 2;

          // Aqui chama a variavel e coloca a linha na tabela
          cell1.innerHTML = data[i][0];
          cell2.innerHTML = data[i][1];
          cell3.innerHTML = data[i][2];
          cell4.innerHTML = data[i][3];
          cell5.innerHTML = data[i][4];
          cell6.innerHTML = data[i][5];
          cell7.innerHTML = data[i][6];
          cell8.innerHTML = data[i][7];
          cell9.innerHTML = data[i][8];
          cell10.innerHTML = data[i][9];
        
        
        }}
      )}
      
</script>

</html>
```

Essa é minha **Index.js**, nela estou fazendo o select e enviando os dados

```
const express = require('express');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
const http = require('http');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');



// Connection details for the Oracle database
const connectionString = '';
const user = '';
const password = '';

// Connect to the database
app.get('/teste', (req, res) => {

  // within the endpoint, query the database
  oracledb.getConnection(
    {
      connectionString: connectionString,
      user: user,
      password: password
    },
    function teste(err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        // DON'T DO THIS, return an actual response to the user
        return;
      }
      console.log('Conexão deu certo!');

      const query = 'SELECT DATREA,HORREA,CODORI,NUMORP,CODPRO,CODDER,QTDRE1,QTDRFG,CODLOT,OPERADOR from USU_VPROEXT ORDER BY DATREA DESC, HORREA DESC';
      connection.execute(query, [], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          // DON'T DO THIS, return an actual response to the user
          return;
        }
        console.log('Banco de Dados Atualizado');
        console.log();

        // return the results to the user
        res.json(result.rows);
      });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta utilizar alguns packages prontos, como datatable por exemplo iria facilitiar muito sua vida;
outra dica: Use uma biblioteca como axios ou o método jQuery $.ajax() em vez da API fetch() para lidar com a solicitação http, isso tornará seu código mais legível e fácil de manter.

Ja que voce esta utilizando javascript vanilla, utilique jquery no seu codigo, vai te ajudar e muito.

espero ter ajudado.

datatables: https://datatables.net/examples/index